# Printing all items of ComboBox using PrintDocument

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, printdocument

I am trying to print all the contents of a combobox in a program, numbered.

**ComboBox1 contents:**

```
Yes

No

Maybe

No Opinion
```

My code so far for PrintDocument1:

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim horizontalPrintPosition As Single
    Dim verticalPrintPosition As Single
    Dim PrintFont As New Font("Arial", 12)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Info from ComboBox1 would go here", PrintFont, Brushes.Black, horizontalPrintPosition, verticalPrintPosition)
End Sub
```

For example, the desired output would be:

```
1. Yes

2. No

3. Maybe

4. No Opinion
```

Thanks!

Comment: The code you post doesn't seems to be related to your problem. What have you tried to print the numbered version? http://whathaveyoutried.com/

Answer (score 1):

You will need to iterate through the `ComboBox` Items collection to get your values, something like this.

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As System.Object, e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim horizontalPrintPosition As Single
    Dim verticalPrintPosition As Single
    Dim PrintFont As New Font("Arial", 12)

    For x = 0 To ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1
        e.Graphics.DrawString((x + 1).ToString() & ". " & ComboBox1.Items(x).ToString(), PrintFont, Brushes.Black, horizontalPrintPosition, verticalPrintPosition)
        verticalPrintPosition += PrintFont.Height
    Next

End Sub
```